# Tools to visualise the series of interactions that users make with an API

Tags: api, analytics

I am looking to understand how users are interacting with my API. I have good metrics for individual endpoints showing their usage & payloads, however I cannot see what APIs are commonly called in sequence.

I'm aware I could use something like Moesif to define explicit funnels to create questions such as "how many users who used endpoint /x then used endpoint /y" but rather than having to define funnels manually, ideally there would be a tool to tell me the common series of interactions being performed, like "57% of users call /x then call endpoint /y and then call endpoint /z"

Anyone know a tool to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Simon. Moesif CEO here. Thanks for the product suggestion Let me file a ticket and see if we can get this in our roadmap.